# Create / Extract zip file and overwrite existing files/content

Tags: powershell

```
Add-Type -A System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory('foo', 'foo.zip')
[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('foo.zip', 'bar')
```

I found the code to create and extract .zip files via PowerShell from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24323413/8161564), but because of my low reputation I cannot ask a question as a comment on that answer.

- Creating - How to overwrite an existing .zip file without user interaction?
- Extracting - How to overwrite existing files and folders without user interaction? (Preferably like [robocopys](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx) `mir` function).

Comment: What does the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx) tell you?

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using? [`Compress-Archive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/Compress-Archive?view=powershell-5.1) is a better option if you are on `5.0` or higher.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

PowerShell has built-in `.zip` utilities without needing to use .NET class methods in version 5 and above.  The `Compress-Archive` `-Path` argument also takes a `string[]` type so you can zip multiple folders/files into the destination zip.

---

**Zipping:**

```
Compress-Archive -Path C:\Foo -DestinationPath C:\Foo.zip -CompressionLevel Optimal -Force
```

There is also an `-Update` switch.

**Unzipping:**

```
Expand-Archive -Path C:\Foo.zip -DestinationPath C:\Foo -Force
```

Comment: Those were only added in PS 5.0 so may not be applicable depending on what version OP is using. They are certainly the easiest way of dealing with a zip file.

Comment: Thanks for the note @JamesC. That detail wasn't showing up in the help content.

Comment: I do have PowerShell 5. Thank you very much!

Comment: How to force zipping hidden files and folders?

Comment: @Yethat If the `-Force` parameter doesn't work, you may need to write the logic to hide/unhide the folders before/after zipping.

Comment: The Expand-Archive is too slow according to GitHub issue https://github.com/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/issues/32 so this approach is not valid for large archives

Answer (score 10):

PowerShell versions prior to 5 can execute [this script](https://gist.github.com/nachivpn/3e53dd36120877d70aee)

Thanks to @Ola-M for update.

Thanks to @maximilian-burszley for update.

```
function Unzip($zipfile, $outdir)
{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
    $archive = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipfile)
    try
    {
        foreach ($entry in $archive.Entries)
        {
            $entryTargetFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($outdir, $entry.FullName)
            $entryDir = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($entryTargetFilePath)

            #Ensure the directory of the archive entry exists
            if(!(Test-Path $entryDir )){
                New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $entryDir | Out-Null 
            }

            #If the entry is not a directory entry, then extract entry
            if(!$entryTargetFilePath.EndsWith("\")){
                [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($entry, $entryTargetFilePath, $true);
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        $archive.Dispose()
    }
}

Unzip -zipfile "$zip" -outdir "$dir"
```

Comment: Some resources are not released, as I'm getting "Copy-Item : The process cannot access the file 'my.zip' because it is being used by another process."

Comment: I've added a line to fix it ($archive.Dispose())

Comment: A suggestion: wrap in a try/finally with disposal of managed resources happening in finally so even if something is SIGINTed, they're released.